# Android: Use different style for lower OS version

Tags: android, styles, themes, version

I am working on an Android app. The app use Holo theme which is not available in lower Android versions. I am aware of that you can set different style in folders like values-v11, however, that's only for customizing in higher versions.

For example, for Buttons I would like Android 3.0+ to use the default Holo and lower version to use a customized Button style. In values/style.xml I have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name"android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonOldStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in values-v11 and values-v14 I have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name"android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
</style>
```

It's now working. In ICS the button still using ButtonOldStyle.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name"android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
</style>
```

To the folder *values-v15*. ICS 4.0 - 4.0.2 is API 14 and ICS 4.0.3 - 4.0.4 is API 15. [See here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

Comment: Do I have to set it for all versions? v11 all the wall to the latest v17?

Comment: I haven't used this personally, but I would imagine you would have to have all the folders between v11 and v15/17, depending on how high of API you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). it's basically Holo theme ported for older versions of Android.